# Can I write programs in C# on Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, programming, mono, c#, dotnet

I am forced to learn and practice C#, is there any applications that support and can be used to write programs in C#?

Comment: What have you tried? Using a simple Google combination of keywords `C# Ubuntu` reveals the answer already.

Comment: fine i will vote to delete this question

Comment: Just from experience here - it is likely that your college course is going to assume you are on windows, and will likely use several windows only features in C# that don't always correlate to mono very well, such as winforms (although I think mono may have since implemented winforms, but I'm not sure). You may run into issues.

Comment: well, since the day i started using ubuntu i didn't go to windows a single time. but i will keep this advice on my mind.

Comment: @AmirRazoR The mono runtime does support Windows Forms. However, I am not aware of any integrated development environments in Ubuntu that support creating them visually. If your class is on the C# language, I'd guess it won't cover Windows Forms, but it might. If you do find you must use a Windows operating system, you might consider running Windows in a virtual machine on an Ubuntu system. Virtualizing Windows does require that you have a copy, though. (Or, if you need better graphics acceleration than a virtual machine would provide, you could run Ubuntu in a virtual machine on Windows.)

Comment: It may be possible to use VS in WINE as well, but not completely sure

Comment: I also had the same question. I googled and it directed me here. Some like  gertvdijk and  AmirRazoR wanted to delete this question, but they may be experts, but we are just beginners. They may know the answer, but we do not know. Thanks to this question, I found the solution. Let this question serve the beginners like us.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes you can use [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

For a nice IDE to work in try monodevelop:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

This will also pull in all the necessary runtimes needed.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me: `sudo apt install mono-devel`

Answer (score 28):

What you are looking for is **Mono**, which is, quoting from the [project's website](http://www.mono-project.com/):

> An open source, cross-platform, implementation of **C#** and the CLR that is binary compatible with Microsoft.NET

Mono also comes with an Integrated Development Environment (IDE): **[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)**. Both softwares are packaged for Ubuntu.

**Mono**

[image: Install via the software center]

**MonoDevelop**

[image: Install via the software center]

This last package depends on the first one. Installing this package will automatically install the other.

Comment: i am installing Monodevelop right now, would this also install Mono, or i should run a specific command to install it?

Comment: @AmirRazoR: yes, it would install Mono. I've also updated my answer to add this information.

Answer (score 7):

You can develop C# applications on linux with .NET Core: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core

After you install it, type dotnet new in your terminal to get a list of application templates which can be generated for you to start.

As of .NET Core 2.0 today, this is the list:

```
Templates                                         Short Name       Language          Tags               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console Application                               console          [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console     
Class library                                     classlib         [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library     
Unit Test Project                                 mstest           [C#], F#, VB      Test/MSTest        
xUnit Test Project                                xunit            [C#], F#, VB      Test/xUnit         
ASP.NET Core Empty                                web              [C#], F#          Web/Empty          
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc              [C#], F#          Web/MVC            
ASP.NET Core Web App                              razor            [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages
ASP.NET Core with Angular                         angular          [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA        
ASP.NET Core with React.js                        react            [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA        
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux              reactredux       [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA        
ASP.NET Core Web API                              webapi           [C#], F#          Web/WebAPI         
global.json file                                  globaljson                         Config             
Nuget Config                                      nugetconfig                        Config             
Web Config                                        webconfig                          Config             
Solution File                                     sln                                Solution           
Razor Page                                        page                               Web/ASP.NET        
MVC ViewImports                                   viewimports                        Web/ASP.NET        
MVC ViewStart                                     viewstart                          Web/ASP.NET
```

The current latest version is 2.0 and covers all my needs.

Comment: I like that this answer seems to be IDE independent but I'm curious as to what kind of programs would be comfortable working with the projects generated by these commands? I didn't see support for Razor pages in MonoDevelop for instance. And VSCode still seems clunky to me with its very strict modular approach to plugins and compilers.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Visual Studio Code using `apt`:

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code
```

[image]

or `snap`:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

After the `C#` package installing, the next dialog box appears:

[image]

Clicking the marked button opens [the next page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910), which provides the instructions for `.Net Core SDK` installation (along with ASP.Net Core runtime and .Net Core runtime installation instructions):

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt install ./packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

`monodevelop` IDE seems is not an option now, because of I could not find it. But if you want to install the current mono version (For example, on 20.04, amd64 architecture) you could use [official mono repository](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu):

```
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mono-devel
```

You could also install additional `mono` packages, which you could find by:

```
apt-cache search mono
```

The `man mono` will introduce you to its usage:

```
DESCRIPTION
       mono is a runtime implementation of the ECMA Common  Lan‐
       guage  Infrastructure.   This can be used to run ECMA and
       .NET applications.
```